# Azure Container Instance Can't Connect to Internet (outbound http GET request failed)

Tags: azure-container-service, azure-container-instances

I have an Azure Container Instance created from the base image `microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016`. The image has mercurial installed and checks out a private repo using `hg clone` but fails with the result `abort: error: getaddrinfo failed`. When run on my workstation using Docker for Windows, the container successfully checks out the repo.

I believe this is a network connectivity issue, because if I run `powershell Invoke-WebRequest http://microsoft.com` the container also logs an error that the `request could not be completed due to failure to connect to the server`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows container on ACI has a known issue about the out-bound network. It is suggested to add a retry logic on any network request or add a 30 seconds' delay before you start your application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#windows-containers-slow-network-readiness

The issue only impacts the Windows Server 2016. It is fixed in Windows Server 2019. Once ACI adapts WS2019, the workaround will be no longer needed.

Comment: Verified that adding a 30 second delay allows outbound internet access for subsequent requests. I used `waitfor test /t 30 2>NUL` to add a delay in the test.