# Azure Web App For Containers - Container cannot connect to outside WCF Service

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, containers, azure-web-app-for-containers

I have a windows container as Azure Web App, it has a connection to a WCF Service outside the container, when i test the functionality of the container locally it works, but not in Azure.

I have a log file in my application inside the container. It says that:
The remote name could not be resolved: 'XXXXXX.azurewebsites.net' <- This is the WCF Service

I have tried:

- Set DNS 8.8.8.8 with application settings on azure [Nothing change]
- Ping google.com [Fails]

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help [@Nancy Xiong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9833314/nancy-xiong), your answer is part of the solution, i discover that i need to apply a delay on my application inside the windows container. I don't know why, but when the application starts the container doesn't have network communication.

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53310518/4443783) [@Robbie Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10486872/robbie-zhang) says it is an ACI bug for Windows Server Core 2016 base container.

I guess Azure App Service For Containers has the same problem in Windows Server Core 2019 base containers.

Answer (score 1):

To set public DNS server in Windows container app, you can run the following command:

```
$nic = Get-NetAdapter
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $nic.IfIndex -ServerAddresses ('8.8.8.8')
```

[image]

For more details, you could read [Private DNS for Native Windows Docker Container](https://www.dontpanicblog.co.uk/2020/08/10/dns-windows-docker/).